# Отказано в доступе к MySQL Python

Tags: python, mysql

Таблица находится на хостинге Ukraine Hosting. Свой айпи добавил в список разрешенных.
Вот код:

```
import pymysql
from config import host, user, password, db


connection = pymysql.connect(host=host,
                             user=user,
                             password=password,
                             db=db,
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

print ("connect successful!!")
```

Вот ошибка:
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1045, "ProxySQL Error: Access denied for user 'hn441612'@'194.44.167.140' (using password: YES)")

Что я сделал не так?
И как это исправить?

Comment: Проверяй, существует ли указанный пользователь, правилен ли пароль, правильный ли модуль аутентификации используется.

Comment: Извините, а что такое модуль аунтефикации? Просто у меня раньше не было опыта работы с MySql.

Comment: [CREATE USER Authentication Options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-user.html#create-user-authentication), `.. IDENTIFIED WITH auth_plugin ..` и [Pluggable Authentication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pluggable-authentication.html)

Comment: Спасибо. Я брал хост, логин и пароль из SSH, это верно?

Comment: Да я почём знаю? но думаю, что SSL credentials и MySQL credentials - разные вещи... хотя и ничто не мешает им совпадать. Ты б техподдержку хостера-то спросил - они для того там и сидят.

Comment: Как-то разобрался. Спасибо)

Comment: Ну напиши самоответ - а то вдруг кто ещё на такое напнётся, а тут уже есть готовый ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Если запускаете на хостинге, то пишите localhost вместо host.
Если запускаете на локальном сервере, то пишите адрес, выданный хостингом и не забудьте дать доступ со своего ip адреса, либо со всех